# Javascript: updating DOM element that has been loaded by XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xmlhttprequest

i have a DIV that is eventually load by a XMLHttpRequest. in this new loaded div should be updates (if exist)

```
   if (document.getElementById('newdiv') !== null) {
      document.getElementById('newdiv').innerHTML= xhr.responseText;
    }
```

seems not working. When i run this check on a Element, which is inserted by an earlier XMLHttpRequest `if (document.getElementById('newdiv') !== null)` returns null and the response will not be inserted. if i am doing this on an element that is in the DOM on load of the page, it works.

How can i update a value of an Element that has (maybe) loaded after page load?

Please no jquery, javascript only
**Edit to clarify**

```
<body>
    <button onclick="f1()">
    <input onchange="f2(this.value)"/>
    <div id="parent"></div>
</body>    
<script>
function f1()  {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {             
      if (xhr.status == 200 && xhr.status < 300) 
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
        console.log(document.getElementById('parent'));
        if (document.getElementById('parent') !== null) {
          document.getElementById('parent').innerHTML= xhr.responseText;
        }
    }  

  postvars = somestuff;
  xhr.open("POST", "req.py", true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhr.overrideMimeType("application/text");
  xhr.send(postvars);
  }



function f2(val)  {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {                
      if (xhr.status == 200 && xhr.status < 300)  
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
        console.log(document.getElementById('newdiv'));
        if (document.getElementById('newdiv') !== null) {
          document.getElementById('newdiv').innerHTML= xhr.responseText;
        }
    }    

  }
  postvars = val;
  xhr.open("POST", "req.py", true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhr.overrideMimeType("application/text");
  xhr.send(postvars);
  }}
</script>
```

the xhr.responseText for f1 will be like

```
<div id="newdiv"></div>
```

the xhr.responseText for f2 will be like

```
fancy text
```

Comment: How are you insering `#newdiv` into the DOM? What does `console.log(document.getElementById('newdiv'));` produce, exactly?

Comment: i am inserting with load an XMLHttpRequest  innerHTML= xhr.responseText; to the  parent of newdiv

Comment: Can you [edit] the code you’re using into the question? I still don’t see how this creates the `#newdiv` that you’re inserting the response into.

Answer (score 0):

remove that !=null condition, so every request it will display new data

Comment: Why does removing `!== null` help? When does `document.getElementById` return anything other than `null` when the element doesn’t exist?

Comment: i am not getting, what exactly you are looking? U want to execute that function on load of your page, using javascript?

Comment: I just want you to explain, why you think `document.getElementById('newdiv')` and `document.getElementById('newdiv') !== null`, as conditions, are not equivalent, since you’re saying that removing `!== null` will help, which implies that they’d not be equivalent. The code is using `xhr.responseText`, so this can’t be on page load, but rather inside an XHR callback.